# How to set the default gcc version for only one user?

Tags: software-installation, non-root-user, gcc

I share a server (Ubuntu 11.04) with other people and I am the only one who has to use gcc 4-4 for my code, the rest is using 4.5. I already installed gcc 4.4 but how do I make it the default for me, without disturbing the others?

The solution needs to work for Makefiles and such.

I tried jw013's idea, but I think I screwed up. I created the symlink with [`ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 ~/bin/gcc`](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/suse-linux/41640-how-create-symlink.html) and now my `.bashrc` won't load again. Here are the error messages:

```
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places
 * /bin/lesspipe
* /usr/bin/lesspipe
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found
Command 'uname' is available in '/bin/uname'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
uname: command not found
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sed: command not found
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
```

Comment: Looks like you screwed up your `$PATH`.  Did you change that recently?

Comment: I think I added `export PATH="$HOME/bin"` to my `.bashrc`. I am not sure, but removed the line after the errors and tried `source .bashrc` which did not help. :/

Comment: That line you added wiped out your other `PATH` values which explains all the errors.  `.bashrc` is not the correct place to change `$PATH` because it is sourced on every new shell.  You should do that in `.profile`.  2.  Most default `.profile`s I've seen already include a `if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ]; then PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"; fi`.  If yours  doesn't you can just add it.

Comment: Okay, how can I repair  my `PATH` values? My now corrected `.bashrc` and `.profile` only return these above errors.

Comment: For a really clean environment, log out and back in after you've fixed your files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method I can think of is to make a `~/bin` directory inside your `$HOME`, add a symlink `~/bin/gcc` to `/usr/bin/gcc-4.4` or wherever your `gcc-4.4` is located, and make sure `~/bin` is at the beginning of your `$PATH` like this:

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an alias. Add this to your `~/.bashrc` file:

`alias gcc='/usr/bin/gcc-4.4'`

It would do the trick but it's a little hackish. I would recommend using jw013's symlink method.

Comment: This seems easier, but I still get an error message when running the Makefile stating that gcc4.5 is unsupported.

Comment: Aliases are only useful to you if you compile from the command line. If you're compiling from a Makefile, it won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

follow the 3 steps

1.open `/etc/profile`

2.edit it with the following content

```
PATH=PATH:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH
```

3.`$source /etc/profile`