# How to change gcc version without root on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, gcc

I have access to a cluster with CentOS 7, which has gcc installed. Unfortunately, gcc version is pretty old (4.8), and is reported incompatible by some of the Python packages I am using, requiring version >5.0. However, since I do not have root privilege, I cannot easily install/delete anything there.

I have followed some answers from stack exchange, installing the gcc 8.4 from source code. The `make install` seem to be successful.

Then, I have followed the accepted answer to one question here ([How to set the default gcc version for only one user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22263/how-to-set-the-default-gcc-version-for-only-one-user)) to change the default. However, it does not work for me.

1. The gcc 8.4 is located at `$HOME/gcc_8_4` with a (seemingly properly working) symlink `$HOME/bin/gcc`.
2. The gcc 4.8 is located at `/usr/local/bin`.
3. `$HOME/bin` comes **before** `/usr/local/bin` in the `PATH`, as written in the mentioned answer.
4. If I call `./gcc --version` from `$HOME/bin/gcc/bin` directory, I get the version 8.4. If I call it as `gcc --version` from any location, I still get 4.8.

So, has something changed since that answer was posted? Why the 4.8 version is taken as a default one despite it coming after 8.4 version in the `PATH`? Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: `which gcc; echo $PATH`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov `/usr/bin/gcc` and 
`/home/iegorval/bin:/home/iegorval/miniconda3/envs/smaln/bin:/home/iegorval/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, but in your point 4, it says `$HOME/bin/gcc/bin`. Is that correct, or did you mean `$HOME/bin/`?

If the former is correct, then your `PATH` is obviously incorrect, since it doesn't contain the `gcc/bin` subdirectory, and it looks like you may have added an extra layer of subdirectories (the `gcc/` subdir) to `$HOME/bin` when symlinking.

In that case, either remove the extra layer (symlink all executables from `$HOME/gcc_8_4/` directory into `$HOME/bin`, or adjust your `PATH` to include `$HOME/bin/gcc/bin`.

Comment: The directory structure is `$HOME -> bin -> gcc -> (bin, include, lib, lib64, libexec, share)`. So, I add `$HOME/bin` to the path, which contains `gcc` directory symlink. My `PATH` is then `/home/iegorval/bin:/home/iegorval/miniconda3/envs/smaln/bin:/home/iegorval/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`.

Comment: The executable `gcc` is still located in a subsubdirectory of `$HOME/bin`. Your shell will not find it until you add that directory to your PATH.

Comment: I guess I have a very unlucky choice of names. `gcc`, which is located in `$HOME/bin` is not an executable, it is a symlink to the `gcc-8.4` folder, located elsewhere. The executable of gcc is located in `$HOME/bin/gcc/bin`, or, without a symlink, in `[path-to-gcc-8.4]/gcc-8.4/bin`.

Comment: That is my point! Just add `$HOME/bin/gcc/bin` to your PATH.